# Как заставить Fragment общаться с внешним миром?

Tags: android

Допустим у меня есть fragment  которого есть listview, и я хочу этот фрагмент использовать динамично в коде. Но для фрагментов нельзя использовать конструктор. Как мне передать в фрагмент   Cursor   например или другой объект класса.

Comment: используйте сетеры/геттеры

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почему нельзя?

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

protected Object mObj;

public static Fragment newInstance(Object obj) {
        MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
        fragment.mObj = obj;
        return fragment;
    }
.............
}
```

Ну и вызывать соответственно `MyFragment.newInstance(obj)`